# If I buy a new iPhone & want to trade in my old one, do I get an overlap period?

Tags: iphone, upgrade

Setting up a new phone these days seems to be as simple as pointing the new one at a swirling pattern on the old one to initiate a synced setup.

If I buy a new iPhone & wish to do this step, yet also want to trade in my old phone, what's the procedure?
Do I get a day or so grace period so I can do this easy setup step?

Assuming, in this case, I am dealing directly with the Apple Store online, so pick up and delivery will be at my front door. I will be buying the new phone outright, no credit deal of any sort.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/shop/trade-in could be more specific on that for sure :-)

Comment: @nohillside - it took some digging even with that as a start-point ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it seems you get 14 days to complete the trade-in, plenty of time to run the setup. After they confirm receipt of your old phone, your payment method is credited directly - so pay up front, money back later.

From the purchase iPhone page, click [See How Apple trade-in works](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/browse/overlay/tradein/learn_more) [this is the UK link, for international, replace the country code in `https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/browse/overlay/tradein/learn_more`].

> ### Here’s how Apple Trade In works.
>
> Important: If you are currently enrolled in the iPhone Upgrade Programme, please upgrade your device
> through that programme and do not proceed with Apple Trade In. [Check
> your upgrade eligibility status](https://secure4.store.apple.com/shop/eligibility/upgradeEligibilitySignInOptions?_np=standard/home/shop_iphone/family/iphone_12)
>
> **1. See what your smartphone is worth.**
>
> Answer a few questions to get your estimated trade-in value. If you
> pay monthly, we’ll apply the value as instant credit to lower the
> monthly payments of your new iPhone. If you pay in full, we’ll credit
> your payment method after we receive your trade-in.
>
> **2. Get it ready to trade in.**
>
> After you buy your new iPhone, we’ll send you a trade-in kit and an
> email with instructions on how to prepare your smartphone for
> trade-in.
>
> **3. Ship your smartphone within 14 days.**
>
> Once we receive your smartphone, a team will inspect and verify its
> condition. If everything checks out, your trade-in is complete. If
> your smartphone doesn’t match the condition you described, you’ll
> receive an email with next steps.
>
> If you choose to pay in full and the value of your smartphone trade-in
> is more than the cost of your new iPhone, you’ll receive an Apple Gift
> Card by email with the remaining amount.

I also discovered my old 6S is worth a maximum of £35… hardly seems worth the effort ;)

Comment: 14 days... My daughter had the phones synched and sorted in 30 minutes. She is 15 so that may be why.

Comment: I can confirm the 2 weeks period for Apple Germany. They also send you email reminders.

Comment: @SolarMike - I don't need 14 days, obviously. Half an hour will do, but not if I've got the UPS guy standing on the doorstep waiting to take the old one away with him ;)

Comment: If purchasing on line *make sure to initiate the trade in at that time!* The return box will be delivered about the same time as the phone or a bit before if memory serves.